# What is the build tool for Ruby codes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, build, continuous-integration, devops

Actually when we write codes in Java, we use Maven for building java code similarly Adv Java uses Gradle and .Net code uses Ms Build. But when we write Ruby codes, how can we built that code.

Is it possible to deploy the code directly to ROR ??

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean by "build Ruby codes"? What kind of "codes" are you talking about? What do you mean by "build" in that context? Please, give a precise, exact, unambiguous, objective definition of what you mean by "build" and by "Ruby codes". Also, what do you mean by "deploy directly to ROR"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is a [interpreted language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language).

> An interpreted language is a type of programming language for which
>   most of its implementations execute instructions directly and freely,
>   without previously compiling a program into machine-language
>   instructions. The interpreter executes the program directly,
>   translating each statement into a sequence of one or more subroutines,
>   and then into another language (often machine code).

While there are quite a few IDE's that make it faster or easier to write ruby code there is no compiler step.

> Is it possible to deploy the code directly to ROR ??

The question is totally nonsensical since both Ruby on Rails and your application code are interpreted on the go.

You can run ruby code with the Ruby command:

```
ruby somefile.rb
```

Or an interactive prompt with `irb`.

You run RoR applications with `rails server` and an interactive console with `rails console`.

While Capistrano is a build tool it does not actually compile code. Rather it just automates the steps of deploying an application, and is an optional dependency usually used when you are deploying via SSH or FTP. Its better compared to other tools in dynamic languages such as Grunt (javascript) or Apache Ant. Capistrano is seldom used when deploying to SAAS platforms such as Heruko.

Comment: I'm sorry about the second quest. I'm totally new to this platform and now I clearly understand that why we use Capistrano. Tysm

Answer (score 0):

You need to built code in Java and .Net as these are compile type languages whereas Ruby is an interpreted language ie it will check the syntax errors or any other message whenever the code/file is being run explicitly.

While you can run the ruby file using

```
ruby filname.rb
```

Is it possible to deploy the code directly to ROR ??
To run your code locally using

```
rails s
```

And deploy the code using capistrano or other tools to some other server.

Hope it clarifies your question.

Comment: Yeah, we use capistrano to deploy the codes. So we don't need to build ruby codes before deploying huh... Since its a SaaS product and we use Phusion Passenger and Nginx for Web Application... Is there any relation between ROR Framework and Phusion Passenger ?    And thanks for your response

Comment: that would be a separate question . I hope you have got the answer you were initially looking for

Comment: Just to give you a bried idea Phusion Passenger is app server linking ruby application with web server(Nginx in your case).